# How can I include my Python program that uses spaCy in Android Studio?

Tags: python, android, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I have a Python program that uses spaCy for identifying a nouns in a sentence. This is my program:

```
import spacy 
  
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
  
sentence = "1 slice of english blue cheese, preferably a stilton (again, or 4 slices for 4 sandwiches)"
  
doc = nlp(sentence)
  
for token in doc:
    if token.pos_ == "NOUN":
        print(token, token.pos_)
```

How can I include this program in Android Studio? It's important for me to able to identify nouns from a sentence a user entered in my Android app written in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there is not Python execution environment within Android, you have to convert your python code into a service that you can call remotely using for example REST/Http for that you can use Flask for example. Other approach is to find a POS tagger in Java for example CoreNLP, but I think this approach is not going to work for either Python or Java/Kotlin, given that in both cases NLP models are heavy and then are going hard to distribute/execute in a mobile environment.